# c# webapi ignore properties in object

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am currently using `C# WebAPI` for our API.

I need to be able to `serialise` as either `JSON` or `XML` only certain properties on an object. What makes this harder is that we serialise the object back and forth for use in the data layer so I cannot just use the standard attributes to ignore when serialising.

I want to create a **custom attribute** (`ApiPropertyAttribute`) and then use a filter in the serialise to only return the properties with the new attribute.  We only want to use the filter for WebAPI use only.

We don't want to create a new object and use mappers for maintenance reasons.

I have looked at media type formatters and converters but can't get them to do what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems you already have a class separation for your data layer (DTO-like). Why not go one step further and take the response from the data layer and transform it for consumption in the context of your `ApiController` ? I don't mean to say create models for everything, but you can return anonymous objects and the serializer will happily take them.

Comment: Hi Simon, it needs to go through our business layer to ensure correct validation and rules are followed when getting and saving via the API. We are trying to avoid creating any new type of objects.

Comment: That's a non-issue. What you return from your `ApiController` method should not be tampered with business logic validation. This should be done _before_ returning. Unless you are using AoP or customer Filter / Handlers for business validation which I don't suggest. When you get your response from your Data Layer, you should _then_ validate  with your business logic and return the appropriate response in that context. If the validation is good, return an anonymous object with the properties that you need sent to the client.

Comment: I see what you are saying (I think). When a user uses POST or PUT to the apicontroller how will we bind the data to an object for easy use?